# Broken Pi - plugging in monitor fixed it

Tags: failure

I recently flew a mission on a balloon satellite. A raspberry Pi was the core of my project, but unfortunately, at 100 km, the Raspberry Pi failed. I retrieved the satellite and noticed the Pi wouldn't boot. I tried everything. Finally, after plugging it in to a monitor then unplugging it, the Pi worked exactly as it should have. Has anyone had experience on this matter before, or can anyone provide insight into how plugging in a monitor seemed to fix the Raspberry Pi?

Comment: Are you using thermal insulation? Sounds like our little buddy got freezing cold and you warmed it up by manipulating it.

Comment: Which model of Raspberry Pi ? How was you Pi powered when it was on the balloon - you make have tripped the re-settable fuse. It takes approx 24 hours to reset.

Comment: Welcome to Raspberry Pi! Please take the [tour](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [helpcenter](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help) to see how things work here. Interesting question. Do you have a log of the Pi's temperature during the ascend?